# A bound on the L^1 norm of a function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:(0,T] \to (0,+\infty)$ be a nonincreasing smooth positive function which is both $L^1$ and $L^2$ integrable.
How can one prove/disprove that
$$
   \int_0^\tau f(t) dt \leq N \; \tau \;f(\tau),
$$
for some $N>0$ and $\tau \in (0,T]$?

My attempt: I tried using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to prove the estimate but couldn't succeed.

Any help is deeply acknowledged.

Comment: You cannot prove it because it is false.

Comment: What is $\tau$ ?

Comment: If $N_t$ is allowed to vary with $t$ then what you have written is basically the mean value theorem for integrals